# Tkinter .see() method not scrolling in text box 1. It just scrolls in the last text box created dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

***Description***

I created a text widget(text_widget1) with numbers 1-100.

I created 3 more text widget(text_widget 1-3) with numbers 1-1000.

I tagged the numbers from text_widget1 to text_widget 1-3.
Now I am using the .see(index) method to find the number that is clicked in Textbox 1 and auto scroll "ALL THE TEXT_WIDGETS 1-3", simultaneously.

But, when I click the number in textbox1, .see() method only works for textbox 20, but not the textbox 00 and textbox 10.

***Question:***
I want the auto scroll to work for all three text_widgets (1-3) simultaneously.

Please see the code below as an example. Just run the whole code for the demo for ***Python 3***.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

for k in range(3):
    text1 = tk.Text(root, width = 35, height = 39)
    text1.grid(row=0, column=k+1) # grid instead
    text1.insert("end", "TEXTBOX " + str(k))

    for i in range(1000):        
        text1.insert("end", i)
        text1.insert("end", "\n\n")

def add_hyperlink(section, tag):
    # when you insert text, you can directly give it tags with 
    # text.insert(<index>, <text>, [tag1, tag2, ...])
    text.insert('end', section , ('link', tag))
    for i in range(5):
        pos_start = text1.search(section, '1.0', "end")
        text.tag_bind(tag, '<Button-1>', lambda e: text1.see(pos_start))

text = tk.Text(root, width = 35, height = 39)
text.grid(row=0, column=0) # grid instead
text.tag_configure('link', foreground='blue', underline=True)
text.insert("end", "(TEST WIDGET 1): Number which I want to find and auto scroll in the Textbox 00, 10, and 20 when I click it \n\n")
for i in range(100):
    add_hyperlink(str(i), i+2)
    text.insert("end", "\n")

#text.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

***Problem:***

When I click the number in Text widget 1, it finds and scroll that number, but only in Textbox 20. It does not scroll in the Textbox 00 and Textbox 10.
I want the auto scroll to be done in all there textbox 00, 10, and 20.

Comment: Well, you're only calling `.see` on a single text widget. Why do you think the others would scroll too? Have you considered writing a function that explicitly scrolls all of the widgets?

Comment: How do you do that when they are created dynamically? Like I am creating a new textbox when a user clicks a button(button a) and when another button(button b) is pressed, it enters the text in all the textbox. Like if button a is pressed 6 times, 6 textboxes are created using for loop, and all the textbox created has the same name, but they are packed side by side using grid. i.e.: for i in rage(5);   text1 = tk.Text(frame);   text1 .grid(row=0, column=i) . Every time loop runs, a textbox is created on the right of the previous textbox.
Then button b is pressed to fill the text in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store all of the text widgets in a list, then call the `see` method on every widget.

Start by  initializing an array at the top of your code:

```
widgets = []
```

Next, add each text widget to the array:

```
text1 = tk.Text(...)
widgets.append(text1)
```

Next, define a function that calls the `see` method on all of the widgets:

```
def autoscroll(pos):
    for widget in widgets:
        widget.see(pos)
```

Finally, adjust your binding to call this new method:

```
text.tag_bind(tag, '<Button-1>', lambda e, index=pos_start: autoscroll(index))
```